# Объясните, что значит string(1, char)

Tags: c++

Прохожу курс по с++ и там в рекомендуемом решении задачи написано:

```
template <typename RandomIt>
pair<RandomIt, RandomIt> FindStartsWith(
RandomIt range_begin, RandomIt range_end, char prefix) {

// Все строки, начинающиеся с '<prefix>', больше или равны строке "<prefix>"
auto left = lower_bound(range_begin, range_end, string(1, prefix));

  // Составим следующий в алфавите символ.
  // Не страшно, если prefix = 'z':
  // в этом случае мы получим следующий за 'z' символ в таблице символов
  char next_prefix = static_cast<char>(prefix + 1);

 // Строка "<next_prefix>" в рамках буквенных строк
  // является точной верхней гранью
  // множества строк, начнающихся с '<prefix>'
  auto right = lower_bound(range_begin, range_end, string(1, next_prefix));

  return {left, right};
}
```

Вот и вызывает у меня сомнения string(1, prefix) оттуда, оно превращает char в строку или что?

Сама задача:

> Напишите функцию FindStartsWith:
>   принимающую отсортированный набор строк в виде итераторов range_begin,
>   range_end и один символ prefix;
>
> возвращающую диапазон строк,
>   начинающихся с символа prefix, в виде пары итераторов.

Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> оно превращает char в строку или что?

Да.

`std::string(число, символ)` создает строку, в которой `символ` повторен `число` раз.

Соответственно, `std::string(1, символ)` создает строку из одного символа.

Эту информацию можно [легко найти самому](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

Comment: Спасибо. Пытался найти, но, видимо, плрхр старался